# divide Matrix by a number

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I have a BlockMatrix and I would like to divide this matrix by a number (e.g. by 2). However, the pyspark.mllib matrix library does not offer any function for dividing a number, only for dot product and for addition/subtraction. How can I manage to divide each entry in the blockmatrix by a number?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `map`?

It works like this:

```
from pyspark.mllib.linalg.distributed import BlockMatrix

matrix = BlockMatrix(...)

def divide_by_2(x):
  return x / 2

matrix = matrix.map(divide_by_2)
```

Comment: Can I also divide by another Block Matrix?